# Billboarding text with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0c208z9e/

Essentially I want to apply the translation, but undo the rotation from this:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

This is the css that gets applied to the text that I want facing the user at all times (spherically billboarded)

```
.inset {
  margin-top: 40%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  transform: translateZ(120px);
  color: grey;
}
.inset:hover {
  color: white;
}
.outset {
  margin-top: -15%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  transform: translateZ(-120px);
  color: grey;
}
.outset:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

I want the text to be billboarded (ie. always facing the user). I know how to do this in openGL, I simply fill the rotation matrix with the identity matrix. However, I don't have access to such things in css. How do I billboard only the text? (First, Second, Third and Forth should be facing the user).

Comment: This is a great question. I'll loop in some folks on twitter to see if they have any ideas

Comment: Great question. I am unsure if you can do this with pure CSS, due to the cascading nature and the inability to 'break out' of parent transforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is full six faces example with letterboxes which always facing to the user.
Using only CSS.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.75 );
}

.origin {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    animation: rotateP 20s infinite linear;
}

.circle {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px 2px limegreen;
}

.circleX {
    transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0 ) rotate3d( 1, 0, 0, 90deg );
}

.circleY {
    transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0 ) rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, 90deg );
}

.circleZ {
    transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0 ) rotate3d( 0, 0, 1, 90deg );
}

.plate {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.plate.front {
      transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 128px );
}

.plate.right {
      transform: translate3d( calc( -50% + 128px ), -50%, 0 );
}

.plate.left {
      transform: translate3d( calc( -50% - 128px ), -50%, 0 );
}

.plate.back {
      transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, -128px );
}

.plate.top {
      transform: translate3d( -50%, calc( -50% - 128px ), 0 );
}

.plate.bottom {
      transform: translate3d( -50%, calc( -50% + 128px ), 0 );
}

.letterBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0 );
    background: whitesmoke;
    animation: rotateM 20s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotateP {
    0% {
      transform: rotate3d( 1, 1, 1, 0deg );
    }

    100% {
      transform: rotate3d( 1, 1, 1, 360deg );
    }
}

@keyframes rotateM {
    0% {
      transform: rotate3d( -1, -1, -1, 0deg );
    }

    100% {
      transform: rotate3d( -1, -1, -1, 360deg );
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="rotate.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 0; height: 0; border: solid green 1px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate( -50%, -50% );"></div>
    <div class="origin">
        <div class="circle circleX"></div>
        <div class="circle circleY"></div>
        <div class="circle circleZ"></div>
        <div class="plate front">
            <div class="letterBox">Front</div>
        </div>
        <div class="plate right">
            <div class="letterBox">Right</div>
        </div>
        <div class="plate left">
            <div class="letterBox">Left</div>
        </div>
        <div class="plate back">
            <div class="letterBox">Back</div>
        </div>
        <div class="plate top">
            <div class="letterBox">Top</div>
        </div>
        <div class="plate bottom">
            <div class="letterBox">Bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can change rotation direction with change a vector in `rotate3d`.
Be aware of that you must change both `rotateP` and `rotateM`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/isitea/svwxmu1p/

Comment: Why did moving the text in a separate div and applying the inverse rotation work? Wouldn't that undo the translation that gets computed as well? I'm a bit perplexed on how css applies its matrix operations. The other div still applies the rotation first, how do the order of operations change when you change the dom layout? I'm coming from a more openGL/C background and css is very confusing to me.

Comment: @SpentDeath That is because of transformation origin. 3D position transform that is applied to `div.plate` doesn't change the 'origin of DOM'. It means applying `rotate3d( 1, 1, 1, 45deg )` to element which is moved from `( 0, 0, 0 )` to `( 0, 0, 128px )` using `translate3d( 0, 0, 128px )`, rotate element about `( 0, 0, 0 )` not about `( 0, 0, 128px )`.